# How to combine same table using union in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get mysql records using union by combining same table based on different id

```
Table name :sample_value

id   width  userid
1    10X12   1
2    14X15   1
3    17X28   2
4    10X12   2
5    14X15   2
6    19X37   2
```

Mysql Union query:

```
select * from table sample_values where userid=1 
union distinct
select * from table sample_values where userid=2
```

Suppose I want to get records based on two different id using union  lets say:

> 1) if userid=1 means it should get 10X12 and 14X15 
>  2) if userid
>   =2 means it should get 17X28  and combine with previous record of userid=1 but record 10X12 and 14X15 not get from userid=2 because same
>   value is already present

so I wrote query for  this union query for this but it didn't help me
    Expected output:

```
id   width  userid
1    10X12   1
2    14X15   1
3    17X28   2
6    19X37   2
```

Comment: @forpas can you please explain after not exists part  in query

Comment: What the code does is: it returns the rows for userid = 2 only if there is not a row with userid = 1 with the same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` in the 2nd query of the `UNION`:

```
select * from sample_values where userid=1 
union all
select * from sample_values s
where s.userid = 2 and not exists (
  select 1 from sample_values
  where userid = 1 and width = s.width 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4F56CATkR131VQoYnZD7j1/0).
Results:

```
| id  | width | userid |
| --- | ----- | ------ |
| 1   | 10X12 | 1      |
| 2   | 14X15 | 1      |
| 3   | 17X28 | 2      |
| 6   | 19X37 | 2      |
```

Comment: thank you so much it is working can you please explain why you have used , select min(id)

Comment: You want for userid=2 only 1 row, the row with the minimum id.

Comment: Actualy  expected output is result set should get values with unique records means if user 1 has same value and user 2 also have same value then combine set of unique values should get it doesn't mean only 1 record for id 2

Comment: Thank you so much perfect work, I just want to know  what is select 1  after where clause ? is it  get only 1 record or userid=1

Comment: select 1 could be select * or select 0 or select null. It doesn't matter. It is a placeholder for EXISTS. So if anything is returned then EXISTS is trye.

Comment: I really appreciate your work, thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

This is a prioritization query.  Others have already shown how to use `union all`/`not exists` for this.  That doesn't generalize well when you have more than two or three values:

A more general solution is to use window functions, which are in MySQL 8+:

```
select sv.*
from (select sv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by width
                                order by (case when user_id = 1 then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from sample_value sv
     ) sv
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also do this without a `union all`:

```
select sv.*
from sample_value sv
where sv.user_id = (select sv2.user_id
                    from sample_value sv2
                    where sv2.width = sv.width
                    order by (case when sv2.user_id = 1 then 1 else 2 end)
                    limit 1
                   );
```

In all these example, I have used a `case` for the `order by`.  For your particular examples, `order by user_id` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the union between the userid=1 and the not matching value between userid =1 and userid =2

```
    select * 
    from table sample_values 
    where userid=1 
    union (
    select b.* 
    from table sample_values a
    left JOIN sample_values b on a.width = b.with 
        and a.userid = 1 and b.userid=2
    where b.width is null
    ) t
```

OR

Instead of an union 
You could try using a join with agregated

```
    select s.* from sample_values s
    inner join (
        select width, min(userid) min_width
        from sample_values 
        group by width
    ) t on t.min_width= s.width and t.userid = s.userid
```

Comment: this query is not working and it seems complicated, can you please  make it simple

Comment: you have error ??  show the error message .. wrong result  ?? show the actula result

Comment: something wrong if I add new  record without duplicate value then this query not working please check it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UNION`, you can utilize `GROUP BY` as well:

```
SELECT
  width, 
  MIN(userid) AS userid
FROM sample_values 
WHERE userid IN (1,2)
GROUP BY width
```

`MIN(userid)` will ensure that you give preference to *earliest* userid. This query would also be *more efficient* than using `UNION` with Subqueries.

---

**Result** [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4F56CATkR131VQoYnZD7j1/1)

```
| width | userid |
| ----- | ------ |
| 10X12 | 1      |
| 14X15 | 1      |
| 17X28 | 2      |
| 19X37 | 2      |
```